# React implementation utilizing AWS EC2 and RDS MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm most familiar with AWS EC2 (ubuntu linux box) and MySQL (RDS via AWS) databases; I'd like to update my development stack to a React setup. Is it possible to run a React app hosted on an EC2 and utilize a MySQL database? I have a free tier micro EC2 instance running with SSH admin access (connected via PuTTY), and credentials to connect to my RDS MySQL instance. Any best-practice advice on how to wisely proceed is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your are mixing up frontend development and backend development.

React is more often than not used in a 3 tier architecture. Where there are 3 components:

1. The presentation layer:

   - Your react app
   - A bunch of static files served by S3 or CloudFront
   - Sends request to the application layer
   - Never access the database directly
2. The application layer:

   - Your application server (PHP, Nodejs, etc)
   - Takes requests from the untrusted client, verify it's validity and updates the database accordingly
   - In your case, running on EC2
3. The database layer:

   - Your RDS MySQL instance
   - Is only accessed by your application server

Please have a read here for more details:

- [Wikipedia: 3-Tier architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture#Three-tier_architecture)
- [Wikipedia: Single page applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)
- [Wikipedia: Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))

Comment: Thank you for the information; as someone learning, I appreciate it.

Comment: If you don't mind, may I ask you another question? How would workflow work in a development environment? Would I be debugging from a single IDE both React files (stored locally) and PHP files (stored on remote server) and pushing changes to separate places (S3 and EC2)?

Comment: There is many solutions available here, I recommend that you pick a tutorial (openclassrooms have good tutorials that start from scratch) and stick to the way this tutorial teaches you web dev. This subject is too broad for a comment